# How can I get the name of a seller on a specific website using golang?

Tags: go, web, web-scraping

I'm making a web scraper in go. Given a specific web page, I'm trying to get the name of the seller which is placed in the top right corner (in this example on this olx site you can see the name of the seller is Ionut). When I run the down below code, it should write the name in the index.csv file, but the file is empty. I think the problem is at the HTML parser, though it looks fine to me.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/csv"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"

    "github.com/gocolly/colly"
)

func main() {
    //setting up the file where we store collected data
    fName := filepath.Join("D:\\", "go projects", "cwst go", "CWST-GO", "target folder", "index.csv")
    file, err := os.Create(fName)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Could not create file, error :%q", err)
    }
    defer file.Close()
    //writer that writes the collected data into our file
    writer := csv.NewWriter(file)
    //after the file is written, what it is in the buffer goes in writer and then passed to file
    defer writer.Flush()

    //collector
    c := colly.NewCollector(
        colly.AllowedDomains("https://www.olx.ro/"),
    )

    //HTML parser
    c.OnHTML(".css-1fp4ipz", func(e *colly.HTMLElement) { //div class that contains wanted info

        writer.Write([]string{
            e.ChildText("h4"), //specific tag of the info
        })
    })

    fmt.Printf("Scraping page :  ")
    c.Visit("https://www.olx.ro/d/oferta/bmw-xdrixe-seria-7-2020-71000-tva-IDgp7iN.html")

    log.Printf("\n\nScraping Complete\n\n")
    log.Println(c)

}
```

Comment: I suggest you to start small. Throw away CSV code from your snippet and add extensive debugging to the part which locates the necessary HTML element. Please note that today's web is a crappy^Wcomplex place, so the element you can see in a page rendered by your browser might have been created by the JS code running in your browser, client-side, and so all these `<div>`s might get generated afresh on each page load, _with different IDs_ and so on. So you will need to debug this stuff, patiently.

Comment: On the other hand, if a page is heavy on the client-side JS, you might attack it from another angle: the page most likely gets the data to render by making one or more requests to the site's backend services, and in most cases it's delivered in a machine-readable format such as JSON. Provided you're able to collect the necessary cookies/auth tokens etc, you might analyze the page's code to see which calls to backend services it makes. DevTools of today's browsers helps big time with this sort of activity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to add `https` or `/` in the allowed domains.

```
c := colly.NewCollector(
    colly.AllowedDomains("www.olx.ro"),
)
```

Comment: Well, extremely interesting; I tried this before and it didn't work at all. Now it seems to work. Thanks!